# What is the correct style of route for POST requests (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have been a bit unsure as how to structure my post routes correctly. In most of my routes I have been adding a 'process' to the end of the route like this.

```
Route::get('auth/notes/{note}/delete','Auth\NotesController@delete');
Route::post('auth/notes/{note}/delete/process','Auth\NotesController@processDelete');
```

Sometimes i have simply made it the same as the GET route

```
 //EDIT USER
Route::get('users/{user}/edit','AdminUserController@editUser');
Route::post('users/{user}/edit','AdminUserController@editUserProcess');
```

This is a bit inconsistent and I want to make my code as easy to read and understand as possible for anyone in the future.

Is there any definitively correct way to define POST routes in laravel?

Comment: no that is not inconsistent.........you are doing it right.

Comment: you can use like this 
Route::resource('users', 'AdminUserController');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use resource routes, like this:

```
    Route::resource('customer', 'Api\V1\CustomerController');
```

That will give you routes like this:

```
    | GET|HEAD     | api/v1/customer           | api.v1.customer.index    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\CustomerController@index
    | POST         | api/v1/customer           | api.v1.customer.store    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\CustomerController@store
    | GET|HEAD     | api/v1/customer/{customer}| api.v1.customer.show     | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\CustomerController@show
    | DELETE       | api/v1/customer/{customer}| api.v1.customer.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\CustomerController@destroy
```

... etc.

See here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers